# Открытие файла py с помощью ConEmu

Tags: python, python-3.x, conemu

Как запускать файл с помощью эмулятора терминала ConEmu без вставки `python`, а просто: `calc.py`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Была переустановлена версия пайтон на более свежую, при этом изменился ярлык питоновских файлов. При вызове без вставки - просто открывается редактор кода и ничего не происходит.

PATH при установке был отмечен. Это не принципиально важно, просто хочу узнать: почему сейчас это работает именно так?

юпд: в системном терминале точно такая же проблема.

Comment: Потому что у вас ассоциация файлов py теперь связана с тем редактором кода, а не python.exe. Это можно настроить в реестре, но проще правой кнопкой на файл `.py` и выбрать пункт открыть с помощью, после выбрать питон и указать, чтобы по умолчанию через него открывалось

Comment: @gil9red очень смешно от того, как всё просто. Погуглил хорошенько и разобрался, проблема решена, спасибо!)

Comment: Оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ассициация файлов `py` теперь связана с имеющимся редактором кода (VSC, PyCharm и т.д.), но не с самим экзешником `python.exe`

Решение: правой кнопкой на файл - Свойства - Открыть с помощью - выбрать интерпретатор питона.